# Control deploy context in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I have a very simple docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: "3.3"

services:
  app-1:
    build: app-1
    
  app-2:
    build: app-2
    restart: unless-stopped
```

and I had the following context added
`docker context list`:

```
NAME        DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                            KUBERNETES ENDPOINT   ORCHESTRATOR
default *   Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock                                      swarm
remote                                                ssh://will@remote                         
remote2                                               ssh://will@remote2
```

Is there any way so that `docker-compose up` will deploy `app-1` to only the default context but `app-2` to all available context (including default)?

I'm aware you can to `docker-compose --context <remote>` up to deploy to only a remote context, but can I mix and match the context in any way?